# How to fix Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException ,CoreFoundation exceptionPreprocess?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, google-fabric

In my Crashlytics report, I can’t find any class file. From the stack trace, I see that when I invoke disconnect the app will crash. This bug is very hard to reproduce, in fact, I cannot invoke it, but I see errors in Crashlytics. How to fix this kind of errors and how to reproduce this?

**Crash NO 1:**

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException 0  CoreFoundation
>   0x1fb907f50 __exceptionPreprocess 1  libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x1fab04284 objc_exception_throw 2  CoreFoundation
>   0x1fb80a25c -[NSCache init] 3  UIKitCore
>   0x228f5a784 (Missing) 4  UIKitCore                      0x228f5b360
>   (Missing) 5  UIKitCore                      0x228f5e598 (Missing) 6 
>   UIKitCore                      0x2291c1c88 (Missing) 7  UIKitCore
>   0x2291ca584 (Missing) 8  UIKitCore                      0x2291c7d64
>   (Missing) 9  UIKitCore                      0x2291c71e4 (Missing) 10
>   UIKitCore                      0x2291ba1b8 (Missing)

**Crash NO 2:**

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread 0  ID-Pal
>   0x100deda14 $S6ID_Pal20ViewControllerC14passportActionyyypF
>   (ViewController.swift:135) 1  ID-Pal
>   0x100defafc $S6ID_Pal20PhotosViewControllerC12cameraactionyyypFToTm +
>   4298029820

In this ViewController of line 135 :

```
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Is this really cause the error?

Comment: yes dahiya. It has a navigationController. this crash not occurred every time.

Comment: wrap the navigation controller and check once

Comment: ok, I will try. Do you have any idea about crash no 1:?